# Different session timeout for different session variables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Right on my index, i have to set 2 sessions:

```
public ActionResult Index(){
    Session["test1"] = "test1";
    Session["test2"] = "test2";

    return View();    
}
```

but i want that session 'test1' timeout in 5 minutes and 'test2' timeout in 20 minutes.

HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout and setting in webconfig will set for both sessions.

so how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by specifying in the Session_Start event. Add the `Session_Start` in global.asax.cs file.

```
protected void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if(Session["test1"] != null && Session["test1"].ToString() == "test1")
       HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 5;
    if(Session["test2"] != null && Session["test2"].ToString() == "test2")
       HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 20;
}
```

Comment: But in my case I need both sessions. Both them will not be null.
Session["test1"] = "test1";
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 5;
Session["test2"] = "test2";
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 20;

this will work?

Comment: @JoãoLucas check the edited answer, does it solve your query

Comment: I tried but the 'Timeout = 20' for 'test2' overwrite the 'Timeout = 5' for 'test1' and both sessions is now with timeout = 20.

Comment: @JoãoLucas Where did you specify the session timeouts in which event ?